# Material-ui modal forwardRef warning

Tags: modal-dialog, material-ui

"Here is the form that logs user in used and I used forwardRef here, In SignInModal I wraped this component but it keeps give me warning"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../actions/auth";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Alert from "./Alert";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

const styles = theme => ({
  main: {
    width: "auto",
    display: "block", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
    [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing(3 * 2))]: {
      width: 400,
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto"
    }
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: `${theme.spacing(2)}px ${theme.spacing(3)}px ${theme.spacing(3)}px`
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(),
    backgroundColor: "black"
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing()
  },
  submit: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  }
});

// const SignIn = props => {
const SignIn = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { classes, isAuthenticated, login, modalControl } = props;
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const { email, password } = formData;
  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(email, password);
  };
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    modalControl();
  }

  //  else if (password != password1) {
  //   setAlert("password do not match", "danger");
  // }

  return (
    <main ref={ref} className={classes.main}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <Alert />
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
            <Input
              id="email"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              autoFocus
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
            <Input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              autoComplete="current-password"
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="default"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign in
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link
                variant="body2"
                component={RouterLink}
                to="/PasswordReset"
                underline="none"
              >
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </main>
  );
});

SignIn.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  modalControl: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(withStyles(styles)(SignIn));






import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import SignIn from "./SignIn";

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 25;
  const left = 25;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`
  };
}

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  }
});

const SigninModal = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const { classes, SigninModalRef } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        className={classes.button}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleOpen}
      >
        Sign In
      </Button>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <SignIn modalControl={handleClose} />
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

SigninModal.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};



export default withStyles(styles)(SigninModal);
```

I used Signinmodal to wrap Signin form not sure if i used forwardref properly, it still gives me warning ”Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ref solved the issue for me.
In your case

```
<SignIn ref={ref} modalControl={handleClose} />
```

```
const SigninModal = React.forwardRef( (ref, props) => {
return (
    <div ref={ref}>
   ... rest of the code
})
```